# Problema al crear un panel y agregarle un label en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, layout

Tengo una ventana a la cual le quiero agregar un panel con un texto pero me da error.
Mi código es exactamente igual al que he visto en videos pero no me funciona. Creo que viendo la imagen y el código se entiende mejor a lo que me refiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    package formulario;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ventana{
    JFrame ventana;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel saludo;
    
    void panelA(){
         panel=new JPanel();
         saludo=new JLabel("hola");
         panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
         panel.add(saludo);
    }
    
    void crearVentana(){
        ventana=new JFrame();
        ventana.setTitle("Formulario de contacto");
        ventana.setSize(500,500);
        ventana.setResizable(false);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(ventana.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ventana.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ventana.add(panel);
    }
    
    Ventana(){
        panelA();
        crearVentana();
    }

}
```

Comment: y qué error te marca?

Answer (score 0):

No me deja comentar(por mi nivel), con lo que te lo dejo en la respuesta:

A mi ese código me funciona, qué errores te está dando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]